# LaTeX aligning equation with matrices

Tags: equations, matrices

How do I simplify this equation so that each step is shown on a different line, instead of it all being on the same line? I tried to use \begin{align*} \end{align*} but I kept getting errors that I don't know how to fix. This is the code without any alignment

```
\noindent
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that the equation holds for $n = k$. Then:\\ 

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}^{k+1}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}^{k}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} & F_{k}\\
F_{k} & F_{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix} \text{(by the equation with $n = k$)}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} + F_k & F_{k + 1}\\
F_{k} + F_{k - 1} & F_{k}
\end{bmatrix} \text{(by matrix multiplication)}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+2} & F_{k + 1}\\
F_{k + 1} & F_{k}
\end{bmatrix} \text{(by the recurrence $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$)}
\]
```

[image: This is what it currently looks like]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

align does work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that the equation holds for $n = k$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}^{k+1}
=& \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}^{k}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}\\
= &
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} & F_{k}\\
F_{k} & F_{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix} &\text{(by the equation with $n = k$)}\\
= &
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} + F_k & F_{k + 1}\\
F_{k} + F_{k - 1} & F_{k}
\end{bmatrix} &\text{(by matrix multiplication)} \\
= &
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+2} & F_{k + 1}\\
F_{k + 1} & F_{k}
\end{bmatrix} &\text{(by the recurrence $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And since you have more vertical than horizontal space, you may try

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that the equation holds for $n = k$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}^{k+1}
=& \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}^{k}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}\\
= &
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} & F_{k}\\
F_{k} & F_{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix} & &
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{by the equation}\\
\text{with $n = k$}
\end{pmatrix}\\
= &
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} + F_k & F_{k + 1}\\
F_{k} + F_{k - 1} & F_{k}
\end{bmatrix} & &
\begin{pmatrix}\text{by matrix}\\
\text{multiplication}
\end{pmatrix} \\
= &
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+2} & F_{k + 1}\\
F_{k + 1} & F_{k}
\end{bmatrix} & &
\begin{pmatrix}\text{by the recurrence}\\
F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaah thank you so much for that! I had &= instead of =& which is why I was having issues

Comment: Why do you employ `=&` instead of `&=`?

Comment: @M.Ng - Using `&=` (rather than `=&`) is perfectly OK; for sure, it cannot have been the source of whatever errors you were encountering. For the example at hand; it actually doesn't matter if one uses `&=` or `=&`. In general, though, it's much better to use `&=`.

Comment: @Mico I agree with you that in this case it does not matter and feel that "In general, though, it's much better to use `&=`." is a slight overstatement. What if the next line starts with a `+` rather than a `=`? We could agree on "Often it is better to use `&=`.", though.

Comment: @marmot - Actually, it's precisely when the next line starts with `+` or `-` that it's most critical to use `&=`: That way, LaTeX will "know" that the spacing around the `+` or `-` symbol should be what's appropriate for a binary (rather than a unary) operator. If `=&` is in use, the horizontal spacing will be off.

Comment: @Mico This I now, that's why I put `{}` after `&` in this case. I just don't line the `+` being aligned with the `=`.

Comment: @marmot - Not wanting the `=` and `+` (or `-`) symbols to be lined up is a separate, but of course entirely valid, typographic concern. To handle this concern, I'd use `&=` in the first line and `&\quad +` (or `&\quad -`) in the next line. Or, if `\quad` doesn't provide enough of a shift, use `\qquad`. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that uses (a) an `align*` environment to align the equations and (b) `\tag` directives to place the three explanatory "asides" to terminate at the right-hand edge of the text block. This, in turn, reduces any need to introduce line-breaks just to make them fit.

Note that I've also deleted quite a few instances of `\\` from your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that the equation holds for $n = k$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{k+1}
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{k}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} & F_{k}\\
F_{k} & F_{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{by the equation with $n = k$} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} + F_k & F_{k + 1}\\
F_{k} + F_{k - 1} & F_{k}
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{by matrix multiplication} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+2} & F_{k + 1}\\
F_{k + 1} & F_{k}
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{by the recurrence $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution. +1